# JSS - How to create rule based on class name on the body element?

Tags: jss

What is the JSS equivalent syntax to this css syntax?

```css
.sticky-header{
  width: 100%
}

body.dialog-open .sticky-header{
 width: calc(100% - 16px)
}
```

I tried this syntax but it didn't work

```js
{
  width: "100%"
  "& body.dialog-open" : {
     width: "calc(100% - 16px)"
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add just an class on open and remove on close

```
open(){
 document.getElementById("sticky-header).className = "sticky-header halfsize";
}
close(){
 document.getElementById("sticky-header).className = "sticky-header";
}
```